# Getting wrong results when n>30

Tags: c++

This program should print 3 last digits (or all of them if the number has less than 3) of 2^n.

When n<30 it works, but after 30 the program gives me negative answers.

How to make it work?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int n, sk,M[20], i,j,kiek;
  cin >> n;
  int k = double(pow(2, n));
  kiek = 0;
  while (k > 0)
  {
    kiek++;
    k = k / 10;
  }
  k = double(pow(2, n));
  if (kiek >= 3) 
  {
    for (i = 3; i >= 1; i--)
    {
      sk = k % 10;
      M[i] = sk;
      k = k / 10;
    }
    for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
    {
      cout << M[j];
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  else if (kiek == 2)
  {
    for (i = 2; i >= 1; i--)
    {
      sk = k % 10;
      M[i] = sk;
      k = k / 10;
    }
    for (j = 1; j <= 2; j++)
    {
      cout << M[j];
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  else cout << k << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you observe when inspecting your progam line by line with the debugger?

Comment: what is the value of `2^31` ? I have the suspicion that you were given this task to find a solution for exactly the problem you are facing

Comment: I dont understand how people write a wall of code without checking intermediate results. You have to debug and test small pieces, otherwise you will never manage to write some really long code. Print the value of `k`, actually the rest of the code is rather irrelevant

Comment: What is the numerical range of `int`?  Answer that question, and it will give you a hint on why you are getting.those results.

Comment: i corrected `int` to `unsigned long long` and now after n>63 all results are the same, what is bigger than unsigned long long ?

Comment: Also, tsk no documenting comments in your code. How can you read this!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any larger types for this, and I suspect that you've learned about the modulus operator, `%`, recently.

The last three digits of `N` is `N % 1000`.

If `X` is the last three digits of 2<sup>n</sup>, the last three digits of 2<sup>n+1</sup> is the last three digits of `2 * X`.

```
int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;
    int digits = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        digits = (digits * 2) % 1000;
    }
    // Fill with zeroes if 2^n has more than three digits
    if (n >= 10)
    {
        std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3);
    }
    std::cout << digits << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`int` is (usually) 32 bits length, but due to how bits are interpreted in signed integers, actual range is [-2<sup>31</sup>, 2<sup>31</sup> - 1]. You are overflowing the variable and therefore getting unexpected results. Depending on the application (maximum value of `n`), use 64 bits unsigned integers (`unsigned long long`, if `n` is less than 64) or consider looking for specific libraries for large numbers.

Comment: Technically correct. molbdnilo has the right solution though :) No need to throw more bits at the problem when you can use a good algorithm

Comment: Right, I actually only focused on the power problem, not the whole algorithm. Nice solution!